# track by $index isn't solving dupes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, mean

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects and display them in my HTML using Angular. I have done this before without any problems by using "track by $index". But the standard error is still raised:

Error:

```
[ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=(key%2C%20value)%20in%20n&p1=string%3Ab&p2=b
```

But I have already added track by `$index`. I am confident there isn't any issue requesting the data as I have been able to display it correctly.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in post.userData.bookmarks track by $index" >
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in n">
    <div><a href="/tuts/{{value}}">{{ key }}</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Suggestions?

Dataset:

bookmarks: `[{"1234": "Title1"}, {"5678": "Title2"}]`

What happens is that a user bookmarks a post that they want to read later. I save the post id and the title of the post to an object and store this in an array. (I actually just wanted to store it to an object like so: `{"1234": "Title1", "5678": "Title2"}`, but couldn't figure it out with mongodb, since it doesn't seem to let you save as object data type.)

Then I want to `ng-repeat` the user's bookmarks in their profile. The only way I know how to do this is to iterate through the array and then iterate through each object. Of course, there is only one item in each object. But this is why I have the second `ng-repeat`. But when I do track by `$index` for both, as one of the answers lists below, it still doesn't give the desired behavior.

Something that could be causing a problem is that I also have a sort of dashboard that can be viewed on the side while viewing any given post. And on the dashboard they should be able to see their bookmarks. Also if they are on a post that they have bookmarked, if they click a (un)bookmark button on the post, it should automatically remove that bookmark on their bookmark dashboard.

But none of the suggestions have worked.

Comment: provide data sample to replicate this with. What does `n` look like?

Comment: There is something you aren't showing here.  a basic angular sample with the sample data that you describe here and the same `ng-repeat` structure works without issue.  http://plnkr.co/edit/ikY1msnz8FvJI1OtwMVI?p=preview.  It even functions when the `key` is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot another ng-repeat: `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in n track by $index">`

Comment: This doesn't work. If I do that a large amount of numbers appear, which I believe are index numbers. But nothing posts as it should. There are 175 numbers that post. When in reality I only have two objects in the array. Not 175. It says there is a cast error.

Comment: @JonRoby: sorry, i had a typo error it's `by $index`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Why u write two times repeat

```
  <div ng-repeat="n in post.userData.bookmarks track by $index" >
       <a ng-href="/tuts/{{n.key}}">{{ n.key}}</a>
   </div>
```

OR

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in post.userData.bookmarks track by $index" >
      <a ng-href="/tuts/{{value}}">{{ value}}</a>
 </div>
```

key is anything which you get from object.

Comment: why y ou use two times ng-repeat ? what is in post.userData.bookmarks object ?